# iOS App Crash if download from TestFlight but working from XCode

Tags: ios, swift, crash, testflight

We are facing a crash when installing app via diawi link or from test flight in iOS 13+ versions, but working in below versions. Also if running from XCODE in both debug and Release mode then it is working fine. Environment XCode 14.1 minimum Deployment iOS 12.0. attached the crash log below not able to understand the exact root cause behind this crash. Any one face this kind of issue kindly help.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x181327c60 __exceptionPreprocess + 216 (NSException.m:200)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x198b56ee4 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1813f86e8 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 140 (NSObject.m:147)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1812c154c ___forwarding___ + 1472 (NSForwarding.m:3577)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1812c075c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
5   UIKitCore                       0x183b5d3b4 __43-[UIApplication _appAdoptsUISceneLifecycle]_block_invoke_2 + 32 (UIApplication.m:1994)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x1812d28c8 __NSDICTIONARY_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16 (NSDictionaryHelpers.m:10)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x1812e9444 -[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 208 (NSDictionaryM.m:267)
8   UIKitCore                       0x1838a251c __43-[UIApplication _appAdoptsUISceneLifecycle]_block_invoke + 72 (UIApplication.m:1993)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x180fe8094 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:560)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x180f89acc _dispatch_once_callout + 28 (once.c:52)
11  UIKitCore                       0x183890a3c -[UIApplication _appAdoptsUISceneLifecycle] + 156 (UIApplication.m:1992)
12  UIKitCore                       0x18399bf9c __78-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer lifecycleWantsUnnecessaryDelayForSceneDelivery]_block_invoke + 232 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:234)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x180fe8094 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:560)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x180f89acc _dispatch_once_callout + 28 (once.c:52)
15  UIKitCore                       0x1837cb4bc -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer lifecycleWantsUnnecessaryDelayForSceneDelivery] + 60 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:226)
16  UIKitCore                       0x183ab6794 -[UIApplication _run] + 1012 (UIApplication.m:3492)
17  UIKitCore                       0x18384fc70 UIApplicationMain + 336 (UIApplication.m:5064)
18  libswiftUIKit.dylib             0x197c3eee4 UIApplicationMain(_:_:_:_:) + 100 (UIKit.swift:530)
19  *********                       0x102039430 specialized static UIApplicationDelegate.main() + 80 (<compiler-generated>:19)
20  *********                       0x102039430 static AppDelegate.$main() + 92 (CardtypeView.swift:0)
21  *********                       0x102039430 main + 108
22  dyld                            0x1027704d0 start + 444 (dyldMain.cpp:879)

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bbc03bbc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dc6a4844 pthread_kill + 208 (pthread.c:1668)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018ba156ac abort + 124 (abort.c:118)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000198c4ede4 abort_message + 128 (abort_message.cpp:78)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000198c3f684 demangling_terminate_handler() + 300 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:71)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000198b5c8f8 _objc_terminate() + 124 (objc-exception.mm:701)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000198c4e280 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000198c4e228 std::terminate() + 60 (cxa_handlers.cpp:88)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180fe80a8 _dispatch_client_callout + 36 (object.m:563)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180f89acc _dispatch_once_callout + 28 (once.c:52)
10  UIKitCore                       0x0000000183890a3c -[UIApplication _appAdoptsUISceneLifecycle] + 156 (UIApplication.m:1992)
11  UIKitCore                       0x000000018399bf9c __78-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer lifecycleWantsUnnecessaryDelayForSceneDelivery]_block_invoke + 232 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:234)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180fe8094 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:560)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180f89acc _dispatch_once_callout + 28 (once.c:52)
14  UIKitCore                       0x00000001837cb4bc -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer lifecycleWantsUnnecessaryDelayForSceneDelivery] + 60 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:226)
15  UIKitCore                       0x0000000183ab6794 -[UIApplication _run] + 1012 (UIApplication.m:3492)
16  UIKitCore                       0x000000018384fc70 UIApplicationMain + 336 (UIApplication.m:5064)
17  libswiftUIKit.dylib             0x0000000197c3eee4 UIApplicationMain(_:_:_:_:) + 100 (UIKit.swift:530)
18  *********                       0x0000000102039430 specialized static UIApplicationDelegate.main() + 80 (<compiler-generated>:19)
19  *********                       0x0000000102039430 static AppDelegate.$main() + 92 (CardtypeView.swift:0)
20  *********                       0x0000000102039430 main + 108
21  dyld                            0x00000001027704d0 start + 444 (dyldMain.cpp:879)

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001812c032c _CFStringGetCStringPtrInternal + 348 (CFString.c:2584)
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001812ab670 CFStringFindWithOptionsAndLocale + 320 (CFString.c:3553)
2   Foundation                      0x00000001829c3db4 -[NSString rangeOfString:options:range:locale:] + 276 (NSString.m:518)
3   AccessibilityUtilities          0x000000019619d960 __46-[AXBinaryMonitor _addHandler:withName:toMap:]_block_invoke.90 + 156 (AXBinaryMonitor.m:226)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180fe7094 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:1517)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180fe8094 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:560)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180f8e73c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 644 (inline_internal.h:2622)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180f8f1f4 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 408 (queue.c:3944)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180f98ec8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 632 (queue.c:6732)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dc698e00 _pthread_wqthread + 284 (pthread.c:2599)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dc69892c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bbbff1bc __open + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bbbff554 open + 36 (open-base.c:101)
2   Foundation                      0x00000001829ded9c _NSReadBytesFromFileWithExtendedAttributes + 156 (NSPlatform.m:756)
3   Foundation                      0x00000001829c8694 -[NSData(NSData) initWithContentsOfFile:options:maxLength:error:] + 128 (NSData.m:857)
4   Foundation                      0x0000000182a34dd0 +[NSData(NSData) dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:] + 56 (NSData.m:776)
5   AccessibilityUtilities          0x00000001962043bc -[_AXCodeItemDecoder decodedCodeItemsFromURL:decodingErrors:] + 100 (_AXCodeItemDecoder.m:68)
6   AccessibilityUtilities          0x00000001961ac6f0 -[AXCodeLoader _createAccessibilityCodeItemsFromBundleMapURLs:] + 396 (AXCodeLoader.m:504)
7   AccessibilityUtilities          0x00000001961ab91c -[AXCodeLoader _updateAccessibilityCodeItemDefinitionsIfNeeded] + 168 (AXCodeLoader.m:358)
8   AccessibilityUtilities          0x00000001961aa79c __76-[AXCodeLoader beginTrackingLoadedCodeItemsWithMode:completion:targetQueue:]_block_invoke + 132 (AXCodeLoader.m:156)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180fe7094 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:1517)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180fe8094 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:560)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180f8e73c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 644 (inline_internal.h:2622)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180f8f1f4 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 408 (queue.c:3944)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180f98ec8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 632 (queue.c:6732)
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dc698e00 _pthread_wqthread + 284 (pthread.c:2599)
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dc69892c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dc698924 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bbbfdaac mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bbbfe07c mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018129bc88 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 368 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018129ff90 __CFRunLoopRun + 1160 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001812b3174 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001829c0eac -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232 (NSRunLoop.m:373)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001829fffd0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88 (NSRunLoop.m:420)
7   UIKitCore                       0x0000000183a35c44 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 512 (UIEventFetcher.m:1167)
8   Foundation                      0x0000000182a0dbdc __NSThread__start__ + 792 (NSThread.m:972)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dc69a338 _pthread_start + 116 (pthread.c:891)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dc698938 thread_start + 8

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dc698924 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6 name:
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bbbfe688 __ulock_wait + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180f88d60 _dlock_wait + 52 (lock.c:326)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180f88b4c _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow$VARIANT$mp + 52 (lock.c:366)
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180f95bfc __DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE__ + 320 (lock.h:330)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180f95820 _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 136 (queue.c:1774)
5   AXCoreUtilities                 0x000000019626fb5c AXPerformBlockSynchronouslyOnMainThread + 100 (AXConcurrencyUtilities.m:82)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180fe7094 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:1517)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180fe8094 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:560)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180f8a858 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 720 (inline_internal.h:2622)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180f97b94 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 340 (inline_internal.h:0)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180f9839c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 172 (queue.c:6935)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dc698dc4 _pthread_wqthread + 224 (pthread.c:2612)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dc69892c start_wqthread + 8
```

Comment: Do you have any frameworks embedded as part of your app? Looks like this is the cause for the crash doesNotRecognizeSelector:

Comment: No, but if I delete SceneDelegate, which has nothing but default methods, I find out the app runs smoothly.

Comment: Were you able to find out the solution for this issue, i am also facing the same crash.

Any help would be appreciated.

@Chetan

Comment: Looks like you have an outlet that was referenced and then you might have deleted that. Now that reference is not there. Can you check your UIScene code?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this could be a version capability. Two things stand out to me.

There may be something around your app lifecycle or UIScene code. There may be a good place to dig in a bit.

```
5   UIKitCore                       0x183b5d3b4 __43-[UIApplication _appAdoptsUISceneLifecycle]_block_invoke_2 + 32 (UIApplication.m:1994)
8   UIKitCore                       0x1838a251c __43-[UIApplication _appAdoptsUISceneLifecycle]_block_invoke + 72 (UIApplication.m:1993)
```

You have some object that doesn't recognize a method call (selector). This is what makes me think it has to do with the ios version. Either that, or maybe you have a delegate object that is missing an implementation for a method.

```
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1813f86e8 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 140 (NSObject.m:147)
```

Without knowing what your code is doing, this may be as far as you can get with just a stack trace